# Private поле синглтона вектор xarray<double> обнуляет свои значения при обращении из public метода этого класса

Tags: c++, вектор, singleton

Использую библиотеки boost::unordered_map в качестве хранилища векторов и [xtensor](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor) для векторизации вычислений. Работаю в Visual Studio 2019, стандарт C++ для компилятора выставлен 17-й.

Есть вот такой синглтон:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

using std::string;
using std::pair;
using boost::unordered_map;
using xt::xarray;

class DataFrame
{
    private:
        DataFrame() = default;
        unordered_map<string, xarray<string>> factorNameColumns;
        unordered_map<string, xarray<double>> factorValueColumns;
    protected:
        static std::unique_ptr<DataFrame> m_instance;
        static std::once_flag m_onceFlag;
        DataFrame(const DataFrame& src) = delete;
        DataFrame& operator=(const DataFrame& rhs) = delete;
    public : 
        virtual ~DataFrame() = default;
        static DataFrame& GetInstance();
        void SetValues(pair<string,string> factor, double values);
        double GetLogLikeGradient(string dfactor, string dfvalue);
};

//DataFrame.cpp

#include "DataFrame.h"

std::unique_ptr<DataFrame> DataFrame::m_instance;
std::once_flag DataFrame::m_onceFlag;

DataFrame& DataFrame::GetInstance()
{
    std::call_once(m_onceFlag,
        [] {
            m_instance.reset(new DataFrame);
        });
    return *m_instance.get();
}

double DataFrame::GetLogLikeGradient(string dfactor, string dfvalue)
{
//much code here
}
```

До вызова функции GetLogLikeGradient всё хорошо. Все массивы factorValueColumns заполнены и используются для вычислений.
Однако в момент обращения к функции в следующем месте кода:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    for (auto valuelist : factorValueColumns) {
            double factorMultiplier = valuelist.second[row];
        }
    }
```

Все элементы factorValueColumns будто заново инициализируются нулями. Проблема сохраняется даже если вне цикла for обратиться к переменной по любому ключу.

Переменная присваивается в единственном месте кода

```
void DataFrame::SetValues(pair<string, string> factor, double newvalues)
{
    string name = factor.first;
    string fvalue = factor.second;

    xarray<string> names = factorNameColumns[name];
    xarray<double> oldvalues = factorValueColumns[name];

    xarray<bool> which = xt::equal(names, fvalue);
    xarray<double> result = xt::where(which, newvalues, oldvalues);

    factorValueColumns[name] = result;
}
```

Перед вызовом GetLogLikeGradient несколько раз вызывается эта функция из другого класса. В момент вызова SetValues все вектора factorValueColumns заполнены правильно.

Никак не пойму, в чём может быть корень проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась и причина оказалась совсем в другом месте кода.

Библиотека нелинейной оптимизации alglib, которая по сути "чёрный ящик", вызывала SetValues и GetLogLikeGradient не в том порядке, в котором я ожидал.
Просто добавил дополнительный вызов SetValues вначале - и всё заработало.

В приведённом коде ошибок нет.

Comment: *причина оказалась совсем в другом месте кода* - вот поэтому пример в вопросе должен позволять воспроизвести заявленную проблему